# C# generics - Can I make T be from one of two choices?

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, class-design

Suppose I have the following class hierarchy:

```
Class A {...}

Class B : A  {...}

Class C : A {...}
```

What I currently have is

```
Class D<T> where T : A {...}
```

but I'd like something of the form

```
Class D<T> where T in {B,C}
```

This is due to some odd behavior I'm not responsible for where B and C have common methods which aren't in A, but it would be nice to be able to call them in D on T.

Note: I don't have access to A,B or C to edit them

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to define an interface for the common methods that are in B and C (lets call it Ibc), make B and C implement this interface, and then you can write:

```
Class D<T> where T : A, Ibc {...}
```

Comment: But, he does not control the sources A, B and C. Will make this solution a bit hard to implement.

Comment: Ah I haven't seen the edit. If such an interface doesn't exist, then there is no direct way to implement class D as far as I know.

Comment: +1 - This is the preferred solution. I added an answer that say how it can be done in *some* cases. It is curious you got the accepted answer though... @Jean-Bernard Pellerin - can you please explain how you solved it?

Comment: Actually in the end I didn't use either of your answers.
I added an extension method to A which was overwritten by the real ones :)

Answer (score 11):

First, If B and C have common methods, it is a design flaw they don't share an interface. That said, you can fix that even without having access to B and C.
It is possible to create a common interface. Suppose you have:

```
public class A
{
}
public class B : A
{
    public void Start() { }
}
public class C : A
{
    public void Start() { }
}
```

You can create a common interface:

```
public interface IStartable
{
    void Start();
}
```

And use it on derived classes from B and C:

```
public class BetterB : B, IStartable
{
}
public class BetterC : C, IStartable
{
}
```

You may not be able to achieve that if you get B and C instances as is, but it can be considered if you create them. In fact, with specialized classes of B and C, you may use the interface instead of `D<T>`.

Comment: I like this answer. It also provides a more generic solution where there is no A, e.g. if B and C come from libraries with different sources

Answer (score 9):

This isn't directly possible.

As others suggest, you could define an interface and implement it in both `B` and `C`.

If this isn't an option (e.g., if these classes are beyond your control), what I might suggest is this: first, start with an abstract class that includes all the functionality you can achieve with any `T` deriving from `A`. Then say you have some methods that exist for both `B` and `C` that aren't a part of `A`. In `D` you can make these abstract methods to be implemented by subclasses:

```
public abstract class D<T> where T : A
{
    protected T _member;

    public void DoSomethingAllTsCanDo()
    {
        _member.DoSomething();
    }

    public abstract void DoSomethingOnlyBAndCCanDo();
}
```

Then you can inherit from the base class for each type `B` and `C` and override the abstract method(s) to provide the appropriate functionality:

```
public class DB : D<B>
{
    public override void DoSomethingOnlyBAndCCanDo()
    {
        _member.DoSomethingOnlyBCanDo();
    }
}

public class DC : D<C>
{
    public override void DoSomethingOnlyBAndCCanDo()
    {
        _member.DoSomethingOnlyCCanDo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do B and C implement the same interface? That may be a better route.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Make an interface `IderivedFromA` that contain the common methods from `B` and `C`.
   *Looks like this is impossible from your question*
2. In `D` cast `T` to `dynamic` and call the methods dynamically
   *The most easy solution, if you can use .Net 4*
3. In `D` test if the you deal with an `B` or `C`, cast, and call
   *Will be checked by the compiler, and is possible from .Net 2*
4. [The Dan Tao answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085909/c-generics-can-i-make-t-be-from-one-of-two-choices/3085973#3085973): Create a specific implementation of `D<T>` for `B` and `C`, these can call the methods from `B` and `C` directly. (Didn't think of this one myself).
   *Will only work if the "user-source" knows it is dealing with `B` or `C`, and does not use the abstract `A` to use `D<A>`. Instead it should use `DB` or `DC`. But I think this is the case, otherwise you didn't need generics.*

Answer (score 1):

The where constrain in C# does not allow you to specify multiple classes as a choice.
Also if you will specify multiple where contains, then they both has to be satisfied. There is no OR logic for constrain.
Here is specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Answers from Grzenio seems right for you. Extract common behavior into the common interface for B and C. Then you can use that interface as a constrain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to the source, the only real answer *(unless you are willing to lose safety by using `dynamic`)* is explicitly check for `B`/`C` and cast.